# Error when trying to set access permissions of file owned by user

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

I'm trying to copy the access permissions of a source directory to a destination directory. The Finder Info panel of the source directory shows the following permissions:

- Source directory:

  - I: Read & write
  - Everyone: No access
- Destination directory:

  - I: Read & write
  - Staff: Read only
  - Everyone: Read only

The following code succeeds in creating a file in the destination directory, but then fails when setting the `URL.fileSecurityKey` resource:

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
openPanel.runModal()
let source = openPanel.urls[0]
openPanel.runModal()
var destination = openPanel.urls[0]
do {
    try Data().write(to: destination.appendingPathComponent("asd"))
    try destination.setResourceValues(source.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSecurityKey]))
} catch {
    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The error message is:

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “destination” in the folder “parent”
```

I thought that an app run by a user has the same permissions as the user itself, and since I have read & write access to both the source and destination directories, the app should be able to copy the access permissions without issues. What is the problem?

Comment: try removing sandbox from your target.

Comment: If you app is sandboxed (it seems to be) you have to create a security scoped bookmark, copying the resources is not the right way.

Comment: @Fault I tried with and without sandbox, and the error stays the same.

Comment: @Fau I tried with and without sandbox, and the error stays the same.

Comment: @vadian What do you mean with "copying the resources is not the right way"? That's what I want to do, there's nothing wrong with that. I don't see why creating a bookmark would solve anything here, since by selecting the directories in the open panel I automatically get access to them.

Comment: Yes it does grant permission ***temporarily at that moment***, but when you quit and relaunch the app the permission is gone. It affects inly sandboxed apps, If the app is **not** sandboxed you should have access permanently even without copying any resources.

Comment: I don't quit and relaunch the app. If look at the code sample, it's not possible to quit the app between showing the open panel and trying to set the URL resource.

Comment: Does the user have permission to remove staff? Can you copy the permissions manually?

Comment: @Willeke You're right! I previously removed the staff group after unlocking the lock (and entering the root password), but when I simply try to remove it even the Finder shows that I don't have permissions to do that operation. It never occurred to me that a process that created a file would not be able to remove a group. Would you mind explaining this in your own answer? Perhaps related question: so is a process allowed to set any permissions at creation time, but cannot modify them at will later?

Comment: I'm not a permissions expert, I just tried your code and tried to do the same in the Finder.

Comment: Well, thanks in any case. You may still want to add your comment as an answer, in case nobody else has an explanation.